# How to approach writing algorithm from a complex research paper

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, image-processing

I thought of writing a piece of software which does `Alpha Compositing`. I didn't wanted ready made code off from internet so I tried to find research papers and other sources to understand the mathematical algorithms, and initiated to implement.

But, I got lost very quickly. So my question is,

How should I approach these papers to extract the necessary details from it in order to write algorithm based on it. Any specific set of steps which works well?

Desired answer :

1. Read ...
2. Extract ...
3. Understand ...
4. Implement ...

---

**Note**: This question is not limited to only Alpha Compositing, so more generalised approach will be helpful. I have tagged `Java` and `C++`, because thats my desired language to implement the image processing.

**What I have done so far?**

This is not a homework question but it is of course better to say what I know. I have read wiki of Alpha compositing, and few closely related Image compositing research papers. But, I stuck at the next step to take in order to go from understanding to implementation.

1. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing)
2. [Technical Memo, Image compositing](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/graphics/Courses/559-f2003/Articles/smith95a.pdf)

Comment: `scholar.google.com` might also help you

Comment: I'd check with the research group that put out the paper.  Often a paper about algorithms would be backed up by an implementation for experimentation.  It's likely they have implemented the algorithm and would make the source available to you.

Comment: Academic authors are [notoriously bad](http://andrewgelman.com/2012/08/whats-stoppin-people-from-sharin-data-and-code/) about not providing data or code, even when asked politely by colleagues in a similar field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you implemented any image processing algorithms?  Maybe start with something a little simpler, like desaturation/color intensification, reversal (side to side and upside down), rotating, scaling, and compositing images through a mask.

Once you have those figured out, you will be in a very good position to do an alpha composite.

I agree that academic papers seem to go out of their way to make implementation details muddy and uncertain.  I find that large amounts of simplification to what is written is needed to begin to perform a practical implementation.  In their haste to be general, writers excessively parameterize every aspect.  To build useful, reliable software, it is necessary to start with something simple which actually *works* so that it can be a framework to add features.  To do that, it is necessary to throw away 80–90 percent of the academic generality.  Often much can be done with a raft of symbolic constants, but abandoning generality (say for four and five dimensional images) doesn't really lose anything in practice.

Answer (score 5):

Write pseudocode. Ideally, the authors of the research papers would have done this, but often they don't. Write pseudocode for some simple language like Matlab or possibly Python, and hack away at writing a working implementation based on the psuedocode.

If you understand some parts of the algorithm but not others, then implement your pseudocode into real code for the parts you understand, and leaving comments for the places you don't.

The section from [The Pragmatic Programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X) on "Tracer Bullets" basically describes this idea. You want to quickly hack together something that takes your data into some form of an output, and then iterate on the body of the code to get it to slowly resemble the algorithm you're trying to produce.

My answer is necessarily somewhat vague. There's no magic bullet for something like this.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend reading articles with complex formulas with a pencil and paper. Work through the math involved until you have a good grasp on it. Then, you'll be ready to code.

Start with identifying the steps needed to perform your algorithm on some image data. Include all of the steps from loading the image itself into memory all the way through the complex calculations that you may need to perform. Then structure that list into pseudocode. Once you have that, it should be rather easy to code up.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to first write the algorithm using Matlab to make sure that you understood all the steps and then try to implement using C++ or java.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the good suggestions above, try to write your pseudocode in simple module (Object oriented style ) so has to have a deep understanding of each part of your code while not loosing the big picture. Writing everything in a procedural way is good a the beginning but as the code grow, it might get become hard to keep up will all you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite) cites one of the seminal works on the topic: [*Compositing Digital Images*](http://keithp.com/~keithp/porterduff/p253-porter.pdf) by Porter & Duff. The class [`java.awt.AlphaComposite`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html) implements the same rules.